# Renaming multiple file extensions based on a condition

Tags: windows-7, automation, rename

Hi I would like to rename a bunch of .bin files into .oma based on one condition: the first 4 bytes of the .bin files are supposed to include the string 'RIFF'. If it includes something else, then do not rename it.

I'm currently using Windows 7 Pro. Is there such automation software already built in that I can use?

I also need this automation to change a bunch of mp3 titles later on...

Comment: you mean bin file of size 4 bytes should be re-named with a pre-fix RIFF

Comment: No... is my description too vague? :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with the following script for the built-in Windows Powershell:

```
$files = get-childitem | where {$_.extension -eq '.bin'}

foreach ($f in $files)
{
    try
    {
        $reader = $f.Open([System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
        $bytes = new-object byte[] 4
        $numRead = $reader.Read($bytes, 0, $bytes.Count)
    }
    finally
    {
        if ($reader)
        {
            $reader.Dispose()
        }

        if ($numRead -eq 4)
        {
            $encoding = new-object "System.Text.ASCIIEncoding"
            if ($encoding.GetString($bytes) -eq "RIFF")
            {
                $newname = $f.Name.Replace(".bin", ".oma")
                rename-item $f -newname $newname
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Kudos Steve, how do I specify the location of my files? I've never used PowerShell before.

Comment: Steve! I'm nearly there! Please reply so I can tick it as the answer! :)

Comment: As it stands, the script will just run on files in the directory PowerShell is in. To run on a specific directory, the quickest way to alter the script is to call set-location before any of the above - e.g. "set-location C:\path\to\the\files\" (without the quotes) as first line.

Comment: Cheers Steve, I had a little trouble with execution policies, but after that it all works! (first time PowerShell user)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know "out of the box" solution.

Maybe write simple script on python or perl or whatever you like is simplest way.

Comment: Thanks, I've yet gathered the courage and time to learn a programming language though :)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, someone had to post a bash solution.

```
find . -name '*.bin' -exec head -q -c 4 {} \; -exec printf ' %s' {} \; -exec printf '\n' \;  | grep RIFF | cut -d' ' -f2- | tr "\n" "\0" | xargs -0 rename -v 's/\.bin/\.oma/'
```

updates:

1. Support for filenames with spaces
2. Realized that the 'rev' trick was unnecessary if the execs were re-ordered, removed.

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with bash... I've heard of it though. Do I just run it through cmd? Where do I specify my folder directory?